# Error while creating Virtual environment in Python 2.x or 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtualenv. While creating, it stops for a time, and it throws below error:

```
File "/home/manoj/venv/test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/lockfile/mkdirlockfile.py", line 57, in acquire
time.sleep(wait)
```

Could there be some file which lock while creating the virtualenv due to which I am not able to create it?

Comment: Any special filesystem like NFS or SMB?

Comment: Yes **NFS** filesystem.

Comment: So I suspect some issue with the NFS which prevents virtualenv from acquiring a file lock. Does it work if you do it locally, e.g. in `/tmp`?